# How to predict output from .csv file which has 20 features output should be in 0 and 1

Tags: python, machine-learning

I have .csv file that has 20 feature and on the basis of these feature i want to predict output that will be either 0 or 1 for each row in the .csv file.

I expect output 0 or 1 from different feature that has float values

Comment: Use any classification algo and check. Recommendation to refer official sites.

Comment: i am not able how to apply any classifiacation algorithm

Comment: is there any error you want to talk about? Kindly post your problem in details,

Answer (score 0):

```
import sklearn
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import tree
from sklearn import model_selection
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

df=pd.read_csv('filename.csv')
data = df.values.tolist()
labels = [0,1,0,0,1....... no.of rows times]

x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test=model_selection.train_test_split(data,labels,test_size=0.3,
random_state=42)
```

use any algorithm(here logistic regression)

```
clf=LogisticRegression()

clf.fit(x_train,y_train)

print clf.score(x_test,y_test)*100

print clf.predict([.... 20 features values]);
```

Comment: thanks for help. But how i will know which row has 1 and which  row has 0 values in labels

Comment: @suraj  first, you need to see the CSV file and need to decide which column is used for labels and other for features, use --> data['column_name'] for label

Comment: Sir how to decide which column should be used for labels.

Comment: Labels is your output features. You can assign it by using any pandas method to labels.

Comment: @suraj that is to be decided by you because what is your goal from the analysis.

Comment: I have a cancer dataset and i extract 20 feature from image like entropy, mean etc. but i don't know which image has cancer or not and i want to use label 0 if cancer is not present and 1 if cancer is present.

Comment: @suraj you need some amount of data in which you have results (training data). then only you can train after you can predict the new set of features on the basis of past data(trained data)